# How to format the YvalueAxis labels in python reportlab

Tags: python, bar-chart, reportlab

I'm creating a VerticalBarChart with python ReportLab.

The values on the Y axis are times as timedelta (HH:MM:SS). I had to convert this values to seconds to be able to draw the chart. So I get the second values on the Y axis.

How can I format this labels according to the HH:MM:SS format??

If this is not possible, how could I hide this labels?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a formatter function for `YValueAxis.labelTextFormat`. See section YValueAxis of the [documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf):

> This determines what goes in the labels. Unlike a category axis which
>   accepts fixed strings, the labels on a ValueAxis are supposed to be
>   numbers. You may provide either a 'format string' like '%0.2f' (show
>   two decimal places), or an arbitrary function which accepts a number
>   and returns a string. One use for the latter is to convert a timestamp
>   to a readable year-month-day format.